# Remove parent from object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the parent of an object like this:

```
const object = {
  "id": {
    "key":"value"
  }
}
```

I wanna get:

```
object = {
    "key":"value"
  }
```

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Use `let` rather than `const` and then `object = object.id;`.

Comment: See [const documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). You are not allowed to change the value. The `const` keyword is short for "constant", which means unchanging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `let` or another variable

```
let object = {
  "id": {
    "key":"value"
  }
}

// ...

object = object.id
// or
const anotherVariable = object.id
```